# Using preg_replace to modify first space, but not inside a group of words using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to replace commas and **potential spaces** (i.e. that user can type or not) of an expression using preg_replace.

```
$expression = 'alfa,beta, gamma gmm,   delta dlt,    epsilon psln';
```

but I was unable to format the output as I want:

```
'alfa|beta|gamma gmm|delta dlt|epsilon psln'
```

Amongst others I tried this:

```
preg_replace (/,\s+/, '|', $expression);
```

and although it was the closest I got, it's not yet right. With code above I receive:

```
alfa,beta|gamm|gmm|delt|dlt|epsilo|psl|
```

Then I tried this (with | = OR):

```
preg_replace (/,\s+|,/, '|', $expression);
```

and although I solved the problem with the comma, it is still wrong:

```
alfa|beta|gamm|gmm|delt|dlt|epsilo|psl|
```

What should I do to only delete space after comma and not inside the word-group?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `,\s*` instead of `,\s+` and replace the matched characters with `|` symbol. If you use `,\s+`, it matches the commas and the following one or more spaces but it forgot the commas which are alone. By making the occurrence of spaces to zero or more times, it would also match the commas which are alone.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sE4iH3/5)

Code:

```
<?php
$string = 'alfa,beta, gamma gmm,   delta dlt,    epsilon psln';
$pattern = "~,\s*~";
$replacement = "|";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Output:

```
alfa|beta|gamma gmm|delta dlt|epsilon psln
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the answer @avinash-raj !
But what if the first term has a space before and the last a space after?
With your solution we would have ' alfa|beta|gamma gmm|delta dlt|epsilon psln '.
How can we have it without these spaces?

Comment: use trim function to remove all the leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

How about using regular PHP functions to achieve this?

```
<?php

$expression = 'alfa,beta, gamma gmm,   delta dlt,    epsilon psln';

$pieces = explode(',', $expression);
foreach($pieces as $k => $v)
  $pieces[$k] = trim($v);
$result = implode('|', $pieces);

echo $result;

?>
```

Output:

```
alfa|beta|gamma gmm|delta dlt|epsilon psln
```

This will distinguish between spaces at start/end of piece and spaces in pieces.